# Newbie trying to interface MLX90614 with Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due, temperature-sensor

Im a newbie and Im trying to interface the temperature sensor mlx90614 to the arduino due using i2c bus. After a lot of digging I found this code which works,but it works only on the sda(20),scl(21) pins. I want to change this to SCL1 and SDA1 near the Aref and gnd pins. How do i modify this code? Thanks

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <include/twi.h>

#define ADDR      0x5A

//EEPROM 32x16
#define TO_MAX    0x00
#define TO_MIN    0x01
#define PWM_CTRL  0x02

//RAM 32x16
#define RAW_IR_1  0x04
#define RAW_IR_2  0x05
#define TA        0x06
#define TOBJ_1    0x07
#define TOBJ_2    0x08

#define SYNC_PIN  2

static const uint32_t TWI_CLOCK = 100000;
static const uint32_t RECV_TIMEOUT = 100000;
static const uint32_t XMIT_TIMEOUT = 100000;

Twi *pTwi = WIRE_INTERFACE;

static void Wire_Init(void) {
  pmc_enable_periph_clk(WIRE_INTERFACE_ID);
  PIO_Configure(
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SDA].pPort,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SDA].ulPinType,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SDA].ulPin,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SDA].ulPinConfiguration);
  PIO_Configure(
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SCL].pPort,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SCL].ulPinType,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SCL].ulPin,
  g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE_SCL].ulPinConfiguration);

  NVIC_DisableIRQ(TWI1_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TWI1_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(TWI1_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TWI1_IRQn);
}

static void Wire1_Init(void) {
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(WIRE1_INTERFACE_ID);
  PIO_Configure(
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SDA].pPort,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SDA].ulPinType,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SDA].ulPin,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SDA].ulPinConfiguration);
  PIO_Configure(
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SCL].pPort,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SCL].ulPinType,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SCL].ulPin,
      g_APinDescription[PIN_WIRE1_SCL].ulPinConfiguration);

  NVIC_DisableIRQ(TWI0_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TWI0_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(TWI0_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TWI0_IRQn);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(SYNC_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SYNC_PIN, LOW);

  Wire_Init();
  // Disable PDC channel
  pTwi->TWI_PTCR = UART_PTCR_RXTDIS | UART_PTCR_TXTDIS;
  TWI_ConfigureMaster(pTwi, TWI_CLOCK, VARIANT_MCK);
}

void loop() {
  uint16_t tempUK;
  float tempK;
  uint8_t hB, lB, pec;

  digitalWrite(SYNC_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(SYNC_PIN, LOW);

  TWI_StartRead(pTwi, ADDR, TOBJ_1, 1);

  lB = readByte();
  hB = readByte();

  //last read
  TWI_SendSTOPCondition(pTwi);
  pec = readByte();

  while (!TWI_TransferComplete(pTwi)) 
    ;
  //TWI_WaitTransferComplete(pTwi, RECV_TIMEOUT);

  tempUK = (hB << 8) | lB;
  if(tempUK & (1 << 16)) 
  {
    Serial.print("Error !");
    Serial.println(tempK);
  } 
  else 
  {
    tempK = ((float)tempUK * 2) / 100 ;
    //Serial.print("Temp UK: ");
    //Serial.print(tempUK);
    Serial.print(" C: ");
    Serial.println(tempK - 273.15);
  }
  //Serial.print(hB, HEX);
  //Serial.print(" : ");
  //Serial.print(lB, HEX);
  //Serial.print(" : ");
  //Serial.println(pec, HEX);

  delay(2000);
}

uint8_t readByte() {
  //TWI_WaitByteReceived(pTwi, RECV_TIMEOUT);
  while (!TWI_ByteReceived(pTwi))
    ;
  return TWI_ReadByte(pTwi);
}

static inline bool TWI_WaitTransferComplete(Twi *_twi, uint32_t _timeout) {
  while (!TWI_TransferComplete(_twi)) {
    if (TWI_FailedAcknowledge(_twi))
      return false;
    if (--_timeout == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

static inline bool TWI_WaitByteReceived(Twi *_twi, uint32_t _timeout) {
  while (!TWI_ByteReceived(_twi)) {
    if (TWI_FailedAcknowledge(_twi))
      return false;
    if (--_timeout == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

static inline bool TWI_FailedAcknowledge(Twi *pTwi) {
  return pTwi->TWI_SR & TWI_SR_NACK;
}
```